# How do I extend another blade in laravel and not affect the styles of the rest of the page?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have used a page designer to develop a new page to my website. This page is aimed to showcase a new service offered by my website. I need to include the header and footer as included on all other pages. Usually this is done using `@extends('layout')` and `@section('content')` and at the end of the page, `@endsection`

Overall, the whole page looks similar to this

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')

@include('pages.random')

\\code here\\

@endsection
```

After investigation, it appears that the line in layout.blade.php appears to be causing an issue.

```
      <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
      <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css?'.time()) }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

This document that is being referred to has all custom styles for the whole site, but when applied to this specific page - it turns all the text from the designed format, to a really small text, and a completely different color.

Before: [Before image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGa6h.png)

After: [After image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2qc1.png)

I would like to know if there is a way I would be able to isolate the fonts and styles in `@extends('layout')` to the header and footer only, and not affect the rest of the page.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: A stylesheet is client-side code and has nothing to do with blade, which is run on the server. If you include a stylesheet on an HTML page, it will affect elements on that page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this by passing a variable to `@extends` and then add an if check for the `<link>`.

Example:

```
@extends('layout', ['plain' => true])
```

Then in your layout blade file:

```
@if ( !isset( $plain ) )
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css?'.time()) }}" rel="stylesheet">
@endif
```

This tells the layout blade to load the stylesheet if `$plain` isn't set.